# how to view the data when searching without submitting | angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, search

in order to make the search process faster, my client requested to view the data when just the search box is filled without even submitting, my code works fine at submitting, what should i change with my code so i can get the  desired result. this is my first project with angular js, i am very new to this technology. Many thanks in advance.

```
HTML View:
<input id="searchInput" type="text"/> // search box where

// the function below "getSearchResults()" will get results when submitting 
<input ng-click="getSearchResults()" type="submit"/>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>NOM</th>
            <th>TELEPHONE</th>
            <th>LOCATION</th>
            <th>CODE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >

        //view the data
        <tr ng-repeat="c in clients">
            <td>{{c.firstname}} {{c.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{c.telephone}}</td>
            <td>{{c.location}}</td>
            <td>{{c.code}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Js source:


var app = angular.module('DMDGroup', []);
$scope.clients;
app.controller('ClientALL', function($scope, $http) {

/* the function put all results in the scope variable (client) in a json 
     form and the results viewed with the ng-repeat on the tr tag*/

$scope.getSearchResults=function(){
    var searchKeyWord=$("#searchInput").val();
    var url = '../php/clients.php';
    var data = {"function":"getClients",
            "searchKeyWord":searchKeyWord};

    var options={
        type : "get",
        url : url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        success : function(response,status) {
            $scope.clients = response;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error:function(request,response,error){
            alert("Error: " + error + ". Please contact developer");
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
}
```

i want the to directly change the data in the table depends on the search results, i'll attach an image of my view[image: i want the result to be viewed in the table as the if i submit, not like the data list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`

```
<input ng-change="getSearchResults(searchVal)" ng-model="searchVal" class="searchClientBtn" type="submit"/>
```

in controller function

```
$scope.getSearchResults=function(value){
    var url = '../php/clients.php';
    var data = {"function":"getClients",
            "searchKeyWord": value};

    var options={
        type : "get",
        url : url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        success : function(response,status) {
            $scope.clients = response;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error:function(request,response,error){
            alert("Error: " + error + ". Please contact developer");
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

Comment: well, but what to do with the "ng-model="searchVal", shouldn't be used somewhere else?

Comment: i am very new to angular js

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen if you use ng-model="searchVal" then no need to use the
`var searchKeyWord=$("#searchInput").val();` function to get the input value

Comment: but i have no component have the name "searchVal" in both html and the angularjs function, so how the anuglarjs function will take the search input without any definition of the "searchVal"  in it? not even the controller, i made some edits to the question, i added the js controller

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen yes.it will take.try it check it works .made some changes to the answer check that too.

Comment: oh sorry i have just noticed the changes, i tried it and it worked like a charm! many thanks :D

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen there is a service for api call,`$http` check it.